# How to construct better ternary statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code set written, but when the `age < 18` it displays the prompt but drops out of the remaining instructions.

```js
let age = +prompt("How old are you?");
let permit;
let cinema =
  age > 18 ?
  "Access Granted." :
  (permit = prompt("Grant Permission", "true or false")(permit === 'true') ?
    "Access Granted" :
    permit === "false" && age < 18) ?
  "Access Denied" :
  "you are under-aged with no permission";

alert(cinema);
```

When I open the the console, I get this error message:
`"message": "TypeError: prompt(...) is not a function"`

Comment: You can start with NOT writing ternary statement for anything that's more complex than `a == b ? 1 : 2`. Use normal `if` statements instead, so it's more readable *to you* and to others.

Comment: `prompt("Grant Permission", "true or false")(permit === 'true')` ?!?!? Why don't you just do `prompt("Grant Permission", "true or false") === 'true'` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do this in one line?

Comment: Yes, my instructor asked that we use one tenary to solve it. After we had done the `if else` part which was working.

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense if you could just use if an else rather than nesting ternary operators. Do this instead.

```
let age = +prompt("How old are you?");
let permit;
let cinema =
  age > 18 ?
  "Access Granted." :
  permit = prompt("Grant Permission", "true or false");

cinema = permit === 'true' ?
    "Access Granted" :
    permit === "false" && age < 18 ?
  "Access Denied" :
  "you are under-aged with no permission";

alert(cinema);
```

Comment: If am correct, this means that there are 2 if statements now. The first one if checking for age > 18 while the 2nd is checking for age<18 && permission. Am I right? @dealwap